# How can I save part of an HTML page by a user clicking on an element in browser on Android

Tags: java, android, html

I would want the part of the HTML file that gets highlighted when you inspect element. I just need it as a string to save. So a user chooses what element code to save by just clicking. Is this possible? Thanks

Edit: This is also not for a website I control, I need it for any website the user goes to.

Answer (score 0):

The data URI will serve the purpose.

```
<a href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8;base64,c2Rm">test</a>
```

when click, a new page will come up with the content `sdf`.

You may use `window.btoa(content)` to generate the URI dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to use ajax and json or jquery for saving a part of the html code to the data.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start researching those.